# Comments in deleted posts seem clickable with incorrect tooltip

Tags: bug, design, comments, user-experience

As you can see in the picture below, when hovering over a deleted post's comments section, this link / button seems clickable: The cursor changes to `pointer` and the forecolor changes, indicating this can be clicked.

Also the tooltip is incorrect and should not even appear as the button's text is self explanatory.

[image]

Comment: While this is really a bug, it probably won't cause any harm anyway...

Comment: Tend to agree here, those comments are only visible to mods and users with 10k rep who should already know how the site works